# How to prove that all the eigenvalues of the matrix satisfy $0\leq\lambda\leq1$？

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, positive-semidefinite, pseudoinverse

Assume that $D\in{\bf R}^{n\times n}$ is a symmetric positive definite matrix, $B\in{\bf R}^{m\times n}$ is an arbitrary matrix, and $C\in{\bf R}^{m\times m}$ is a symmetric positive semidefinite matrix, such that the matrix $S=(C+BD^{-1}B^T)$ is nonsingular. Let $X=D^{-1}-D^{-1}B^TS^{-1}BD^{-1}$. Prove that all the eigenvalues of the matrix $D^{1/2}XD^{1/2}$ satisfy $0\leq\lambda\leq1$？

I try to utilize Woodbury formula to prove the above assertion, but it requires $C$ to be nonsingular which is not guaranteed. How can I prove the above assertion? Is there any hint related?

Answer (score 1):

As usual, write $A\le B$ to mean that the spectrum of $B-A$ is positive.

Then $S=C+BD^{-1}B^T\ge C$ since $D^{-1}>0$.
Hence $$0\le S^{-1}C\le 1\\
I=S^{-1}(C+BD^{-1}B^T)\\
\therefore\ 0\le I-S^{-1}BD^{-1}B^T\le 1\\
\therefore\ 0\le S^{-1}BD^{-1}B^T\le 1$$
But in general $AB$ and $BA$ have the same eigenvalues, except possibly for $0$. In this case, this does not matter, so $$0\le B^TS^{-1}BD^{-1}\le1\\
\therefore\ 0\le I-B^TS^{-1}BD^{-1}\le 1\\
\therefore\ 0\le DX\le 1\\
\therefore\ 0\le D^{1/2}XD^{1/2}\le 1$$ by conjugating with $D^{1/2}$.